# How to get top value from css file to .js controller in sencha touch?

Tags: ios, iphone, css, sencha-touch

I am new to `sencha touch`. I am developing an `iOS` application using `sencha touch`. I wrote `top` for a lebel in app.css file using cls. I have tried like this.

```
console.log(Ext.getCmp('location_label').getTop());
```

But it's not working. I am getting if use above line. Can any one help?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get return value from the method getTop(), you need to give 'top:number' inside  'label', not in css.

{ xtype:'label',id:'location_label',top:5}

Comment: i am getting if i will give inside. I need to get it from css.

Comment: This getTop() sencha specific code. so it wil work only if you give in css